# Do different sums in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have an issue on a query:
I have 2 tables.

Table 1:
[image]

Table 2: [image]

I'm trying to join both tables on DateHour (that works) and for each campaign, for each PRF_ID, for each LENGTH and for each Type, to calculate count the occurences of the HPP column of table 2, year per year.

So for instance, for a given PRF_ID, length,type and campaign, I will have a range of dates in Table 1 between 01/04/2019 and 01/04/2020.
In this case, in my query, I need a new column giving me for all the dates between 01/04/2019 and 31/12/2019 the sum of HPP ocurrences in this period.
For 2020, the sum would be between 01/01/2020 and 01/04/2020.

I tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.DateHour,
SUM(Table2.HPP) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Table2.DateHour)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table2.DateHour=Table1.DateHour
```

But that gives me really odd results, the `OVER PARTITION BY` does not seem to work.

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your full attempt(s) will help us help you. `SUM OVER PARTITION YEAR(DateHour)` is not valid T-SQL at all, and it's unclear what it's attempting to do.

Comment: Like what, you haven't added any sample data to your question.

Comment: @MFA You should edit your question and add it there with proper formatting instead of in a comment.

Comment: I just did it, sorry for the mess, I'm quite new here

Comment: Images don't really help us help you here. Post data as text; preferably DDL and DML statements and if you tabular formatted `text`. Don't forget we ned your expected results and your full attempt(s). You've only posted images of one of those.

Comment: Your image doesn't show an `IsHour` column.

Comment: I mixed the names, I just edited it. Thanks

Comment: You seem to be driving some of this logic with date filters. It's hard to be certain what that query looks like though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing because it mixes terminology.

### Count versus sum

> ... to calculate **count** the occurences ... the **sum** would be ...

Counting occurrences is not the same as adding them up. Every records that can be joined counts as an occurence. Calculating the sum means adding up the values of a column. I added both calculations to the solution below (see `IsHour_Sum` versus `Table2_Count`).

### Grouping on combinations

> Do different sums in the same query [question title]

> ... and for each campaign, for each PRF_ID, for each LENGTH and for each Type ...

Do you want to aggregate over each *combination* of those columns or do you want to aggregate over each column *individually*? I have assumed you are after the *combinations* in my solution. Example to clarify:

If

- column `A` has 3 possible values (`A1, A2, A3`) and
- column `B` has 2 possible values (`B1, B2`)

Then

- there are 5 counts (`3 + 2`) when aggregating (`A`) and (`B`) indivually
- there are 6 counts (`3 * 2`) when aggregating each combination of (`A,B`)

Again:

```
A1 -> count 1     vs     A1,B1 -> count 1
A2 -> count 2            A1,B2 -> count 2
A3 -> count 3            A2,B1 -> count 3
B1 -> count 4            A2,B2 -> count 4
B2 -> count 5            A3,B1 -> count 5
                         A3,B2 -> count 6
```

### Sample data

I left out the column `Value` from `table1` because it is not part of your question. I also changed the dates for `table2` to `2018-05-23` to match with the majority of the `table1` records. Otherwise all counts and sums would be `0`.

```
declare @table1 table
(
    DateHour datetime,
    PRF_ID int,
    Campaign nvarchar(5),
    Length int,
    ContractType nvarchar(5)
);

insert into @table1 (DateHour, PRF_ID, Campaign, Length, ContractType) values
('2018-05-23 00:00', 1, 'Q218', 1, 'G'),
('2018-05-23 01:00', 1, 'Q218', 1, 'G'),
('2018-05-23 02:00', 1, 'Q218', 1, 'G'),
('2020-05-23 03:00', 1, 'Q120', 1, 'G'),
('2018-05-23 04:00', 1, 'Q218', 1, 'G'),
('2019-07-23 01:00', 1, 'Q219', 1, 'G');

declare @table2 table
(
    DateHour datetime,
    HPP int
);

insert into @table2 (DateHour, HPP) values
('2018-05-23 00:00', 0),
('2018-05-23 01:00', 0),
('2018-05-23 02:00', 1),
('2018-05-23 03:00', 0),
('2018-05-23 04:00', 1),
('2018-05-23 05:00', 0),
('2018-05-23 06:00', 0),
('2018-05-23 07:00', 0);
```

### Solution

The easiest way to aggregation on the year of the dates, is to split of that part as a new column instead of using a `over(partition by ...)` construction. If you do not need the new column `Year` in your output, then you can simply remove it from the field list (after `select`), but it must remain in the grouping clause (after `group by`).

```
select  year(t1.DateHour) as 'Year',
        t1.PRF_ID,
        t1.Campaign,
        t1.Length,
        t1.ContractType,
        isnull(sum(t2.HPP), 0) as 'IsHour_Sum',
        count(t2.DateHour) as 'Table2_Count'
from @table1 t1
left join @table2 t2
    on t2.DateHour = t1.DateHour
/* -- specify date filter as required
where t1.DateHour >= '2019-04-01 00:00'
  and t1.DateHour <  '2020-04-01 00:00'
*/
group by    year(t1.DateHour),
            t1.PRF_ID,
            t1.Campaign,
            t1.Length,
            t1.ContractType;
```

### Result

```
Year        PRF_ID      Campaign Length      ContractType IsHour_Sum  Table2_Count
----------- ----------- -------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ------------
2018        1           Q218     1           G            2           4
2019        1           Q219     1           G            0           0
2020        1           Q120     1           G            0           0
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I mixed SUM and COUNT, probably because Table2.HPP contains only 0 or 1.
The code you gave me almost works, there is still an issue that i cannot solve: for a given combination of PRF_ID,Campaign, Length and ContractType, let's say I have a start_date=01/04/2019 and an end_date=01/04/2020:
Table 2 will have zeroes and ones for every single day of 2019 and 2020.
Therefore, the sum, for 2019 for example will be the sum for the whole year and not only on the period april-december.

I don't know if it's clear or not, I'm sorry, that is quite confusing !

Comment: @MFA Just apply an additional range on the `table1` selection. I have updated my solution with some commented code for the requested range. For the current sample data this will reduce the result to the 2019 line.

Comment: I finally did it by decomposing all my date ranges by pieces to get the same date range for each. Then I applied the GROUP BY on it